# How do I workaround international code prefix?

Tags: voip

The place where I work at is based out of Hong Kong. We're trying to integrate a VoIP system akin to AirCall/ CloudTalk etc. that provide features like call recording, CRM-integration etc. These systems typically allow purchasing local/international numbers to start calling from their applications. However, we've hit a roadblock wherein HK locals wouldn't answer calls made from these system because they need to adhere to the +852 (HK prefix) format - they percieve these as spam/tele-marketing calls. How do I achieve the core requirements without our number appearing as international (i.e, prefixed with country code) to ensure optimal response rate?

Answer (score 0):

Using a local SIP trunking provider is one of the easier ways to ensure Caller ID is passed out onto the network in the country where the calls terminate to.

Guaranteed Caller ID presention is a "premium" feature of international call origination, so many of the cheaper international SIP providers won't offer a guarantee the caller ID will be passed through in the terminating country, so it's worth asking. A local SIP trunking provider in HK for example would be able to present the caller ID HKers are expecting, albeit with the added inconvenience of having to have a provider in each country you're operating in.